# Stretching or resizing a UICollectionViewCell to the size of a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uikit, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

Ok so, i have UICollectionView in which each cell contains a tableview, scrolling left to right on portrait mode on an iPhone 5. The collection view is set to the width and height of the screen minus a nav bar and subnav UIView on the top and tab bar on the bottom.The collection view cell is set to the width and height of the entire collection view in interface builder. Using autolayout, The table view is also set to the width and height of the cell. Every table view represents values for a certain day, scrolling to the left or right gives another day with another list. Is it possible to make the collection view cell resize to the size of the collection view? So that when I turn to landscape the cell can fill the collection view horizontally and therefore the tableView will fill the cell the same way? Just like in portrait?  Not sure if this can be done with autolayout in interface bulder, or I would have to create a new layout for the cell every time I change orientations.  Thank you for any help! If my question is unclear please specify what i'm missing and I will respond promptly.